# How to use nested switch statements with multiple variables in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to make a calculator to find the amount of delay compensation owed depending on what kind of ticket they had, the price of their ticket and the length of time they were delayed for. I thought that I could do this with a few nested switch statements.  I've tried to follow the answers to other questions here but I cant quite get it to work. feel very out of my depth and I've definitely overcomplicated it.

Here's what I've got:

```
function dropdownChange()
{
var ticket=document.getElementById("ticket").value;
}
function calculateComp() {
var price=document.getElementById("ticketprice").value;
var delay=document.getElementById("delay").value;
var ticket = dropdownChange();
var totalDP = '';
switch (ticket) {
    case "single":
        switch (true) {
            case (delay <= 29):
                totalComp = 0;
                break;
            case (delay <= 59):
                totalComp = price * 0.5;
                break;
            case (delay <= 119):
                totalComp = price;
                break;
            case (delay >= 120):
                totalComp = price;
                break;
            }
        break;
    case "return":
        switch (true) {
            case (delay < 29):
                totalComp = 0;
                break;
            case (delay < 59):
                totalComp = price * 0.25;
                break;
            case (delay < 119):
                totalComp = price * 0.5;
                break;
            case (delay >= 120):
                totalComp = price;
                break;
            }
        }  
    document.getElementById("repay").innerHTML = "£"+totalComp;
}
```

html:

```
    <form action="" id="compform" onsubmit="return false;">
   <fieldset>
   <h2>Compensation Calculator</h2>
    <p>
       <label >Ticket Price</label>
    <input type="number"  id="ticketprice"
    name="ticketprice"/>
    </p>
    
    <p>
       <label >Delay Time</label>
    <input type="number"  id="delay"
    name="delayTime" value="">
    </p>
    
   <label >Ticket Type</label>
    <select id="ticket" name='ticket' onchange="dropdownChange()">
    <option value="single">Single</option>
    <option value="return">Return</option>
    <option value="season">Season</option>
   </select>
    
    <p>
   <button for='go' class="submit" onclick="calculateTotalComp();">
   Go!</button>

    <div id="repay"></div>
```

I'm likely making a very obvious typing error or just not fully understanding how JS works. I'm pulling hair out over this so any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: `ticket` is `undefined` since you don't return it from `dropdownChange()`?

Comment: You've also misnamed your handler and `ticketComp`. `calculateTotalComp()` should be `calculateTotalDP()` or vice versa. Voting to close as typo

Comment: You really don't want to nest switch statements if you can help it.

Comment: I'd recommend against nested switches, but if you're going to have them, I'd put it into a separate function and use `return` instead to simplify it.

Answer (score 1):

I see.
Post the modified code. Hope it helps for you little by little. Good luck.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Test</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="" id="compform" onsubmit="return false;">
        <fieldset>
            <h2>Compensation Calculator</h2>
            <p>
            <label >Ticket Price</label>
            <input type="number"  id="ticketprice"
            name="ticketprice"/>
            </p>
            
            <p>
            <label >Delay Time</label>
            <input type="number"  id="delay"
            name="delayTime" value="">
            </p>
                
            <label >Ticket Type</label>
            <select id="ticket" name='ticket' onchange="dropdownChange()">
                <option value="single">Single</option>
                <option value="return">Return</option>
                <option value="season">Season</option>
            </select>
                
            <p>
            <button for='go' class="submit" onclick="calculateTotalComp();">Go!</button>

            <div id="repay"></div>
        </fieldset>
    </form>
</body>
<script>
    let ticket = "single";

    function dropdownChange() {
        ticket = document.getElementById("ticket").value;
    }

    function calculateTotalComp() {
        var price = document.getElementById("ticketprice").value;
        var delay = document.getElementById("delay").value;
        var totalDP = '';

        var totalComp = 0;
        
        switch (ticket != "reason") {
            case (delay <= 29):
                totalComp = 0;
                if (ticket != "return" && delay != 29) break;
            case (delay <= 59):
                totalComp = price * 0.25;
                console.log(totalComp);
                if (ticket != "return" && delay != 59) break;
            case (delay <= 119):
                totalComp = price * 0.5;
                if (ticket != "return" && delay != 119) break;
            case (delay >= 120):
                totalComp = price;
                break;
        }

        document.getElementById("repay").innerHTML = "£"+totalComp;
    }
</script>
</html>
```

Comment: Tysm! That makes way more sense :)